# Decimal to Percentage formatter

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm using this format `{0:P2}` it is returning proper value but the problem is it is giving space between value and % symbol. how do i remove that space?

Example :

```
String.Format("Value: {0:P2}.", 0.8526) // formats as 85.26 %
```

I Want to remove space between 85.26 and % symbol.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
//using System.Globalization;
string result = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Value: {0:0.00%}", 0.8526); //85.26%
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm find another format for this {0:0.#%}.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting of a percent value is controlled by the [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) used when formatting the value. To be more specific, the [`NumberFormatInfo.PercentPositivePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentpositivepattern.aspx) controls the formatting and for you the value of that property is 0 leading to the pattern `n %` but you want to use 1 instead resulting in `n%`. In your case, because you do not specify a `CultureInfo` or `NumberFormatInfo` when formatting the value, you are using the current culture for formatting (the culture set by the user in Windows). You can make a clone of this and modify it:

```
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var numberFormat = (NumberFormatInfo) cultureInfo.NumberFormat.Clone();
numberFormat.PercentPositivePattern = 1;
var result = String.Format(numberFormat, "Value: {0:P2}.", 0.8526);
```

To format negative numbers you will have to modify [`NumberFormatInfo.PercentNegativePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentnegativepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
string ret = "Value: " + String.Format("{0:P2}.", 0.8526).Replace(" ", "");
```

Returns: Value: 85.26%.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm find another format for this {0:0.#%}.

Answer (score 0):

A long way to do it would be:

```
String formatedPercent = String.Format("{0:P2}",0.8526);
String[] splitFormated = formatedPercent.Split(" ");
Sting output = "Value: " + splitFormated[0] + splitFormated[1];
```

Returns "Value: 85.26%"